# Raspberry Pi 2 V4L2 not working with VLC

Tags: linux, debian, vlc, raspberry-pi2, v4l2

I've currently started messing around with the Raspberry Pi 2 with a NOiR cam. The main idea is the get this camera to stream to another computer.

I've installed the V4L2 driver. Had to upgrade to "Jessie" to make this happen due to bugs in the install procedure.
and VLC for network streaming.

I can capture video from my camera local using either

```
raspivid -t 5000
```

or

```
v4l2-ctl --overlay=1 # enable viewfinder
v4l2-ctl --overlay=0 # disable viewfinder
```

Just fine.

However when I try to stream the video using the following command

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 --sout "#standard{access=udp,mux=ts,dst=172.20.1.105:5000}"
```

Nothing happens, I'm trying to monitor my network with WireShark and nothing happens.

after executing the above command the following messages are seen

```
pi@cam1 ~ $ cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 --sout "#standard{access=udp,mux=ts,dst=172.20.1.105:5000}"
VLC media player 2.2.0-rc2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.0-rc1-118-g22fda39)
[01ef6378] core audio output error: no suitable audio output module
[01e83780] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
```

and nothing more.

What am I missing?

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be about programming but just how to use various programs on the raspberry pi.  Might be better suited for http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you. didn't know there where on specific for raspi